# how to encode arabic characters in python

Tags: python, encoding, pydev

I'm stuck encoding arabic characters using python 2.7 in pydev eclipse
I tried the `# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-` solution but no results.

I get errors:

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xd8' in file E:\python\RH\src\recherche.py on line 371, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

I want to print  this arabic word `صباح الخير يا صاحبي` in pydev environment or print it in wx  widget graphically.

Comment: Works for me ... did you make sure to put the `# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-` comment in the first two lines of the file?

Comment: Zero Piraeus, tnaks for your post, actualy yeah, i put # -*- coding: UTF-8 -*- comment on the first line of the class, but still the same error.. please can you post your code here so i can test it, i might need to install some packages on python27 directory !

Comment: Thanks a lot friends i found the solution, i shoud add this line  # -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-, and use this type of string u"صباح الخير يا صاحبي"

Comment: First two lines of the **file**, not the class; see [PEP 263](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/). My test code was a file with two lines: the encoding comment and a print statement.